# divs in button_to in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

When I try to use button_to for link smthing - rails add to that button  tag and my design is broke. How i can fix that? For example:

```
<%= f.submit %>
<%= button_to 'Back', resumes_path %>
```

I know that i can use somthing like link_to, but in this situation i need to use button_to. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please create any class name or div id and write button css.

```
<%= link_to 'Back', resumes_path , :class => "button_css" %>
```

and write style,

```
.button_css
{
   // your button style...
}
```

---

**Edit : Try this**

```
<% content_tag :button :type => :submit do %>Button<% end %>
```

This will create a button, you can then add onclick event to redirect the page.

Comment: and there is no decision for button to?